# How do perform operation with two separate arrays one containing the value and another containing the operand

Tags: javascript

```
var num = [12, 13, 15, 22];

var oper = ["+", "-", "*"];
```

How can I make a loop so, I can do the following operation

```
12 + 13 - 15 * 22
```

I tried to do it like the following:

```
for(var t = 0; t < num.length - 1; t++) {
  retVal += num[t] oper[t] num[t+1]
}
```

But that didn't really work for me

How can I achieve what I am looking to do.

P.s. operand precedence is not needed here.

Comment: try this: `eval('retVal += num[t] '+oper[t]+' num[t+1]');`

Comment: Will overshoot array length using that `for()`

Comment: @charlietfl How? I am starting from 0 to less than the length of array

Comment: Yes but on last iteration... `num[t+1]` is undefined

Comment: @charlietfl true you are right. I don't know why i used my old code but i updated to make it correct.

Comment: Are you expecting it to work somewhat like a pocket calculator, meaning this is equivalent to `(((12 + 13) - 15) * 22) ~~> ((25 - 15) * 22) ~~> (10 * 22) ~~> 220`?  Or are you expecting it to take into account the usual mathematical operator precedence, `((12 + 13) - (15 * 22)) ~~> (25 - 330) ~~> -305`?

Comment: yes like a calculator @ScottSauyet

Comment: Which calculator works like that?

Comment: @trincot I am not sure as I was trying to build one to see if it works.

Comment: @trincot: most of the simple calculators on the market, it seems to me.  I enter `1  2  +  1  3  -  1  5   *  2  2  =` and get `220`.  More sophisticated calculators actually take into account the order of operations, not calculating as they go.

Answer (score 3):

You could join the array with an array of separatoes and the eval the expression. This respects the operator precedence.

```js
const
    join = ([a, b, ...array], [s, ...separators]) => array.length
        ? join([a + s + b, ...array], separators)
        : a + s + b;

var num = [12, 13, 15, 22],
    oper = ["+", "-", "*"],
    term = join(num, oper);

console.log(term);
console.log(eval(term));
```

If you do not need the operator precedence, you could take an object with the operators and reduce the array.

```js
var num = [12, 13, 15, 22],
    oper = ["+", "-", "*"],
    op = { '+': (a, b) => a + b, '-': (a, b) => a - b, '*': (a, b) => a * b },
    opValues = oper.values(),
    result = num.reduce((a, b) => op[opValues.next().value](a, b));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thank you but operator precedence doesn't matter, it's in the order it appears.

Comment: Please specify this explicitly in the question, @Si8.

Comment: That latter answer is extremely elegant... or twisted, and I'm not sure which!  :-)  I never take advantage of the no-initializer version of `reduce` (for what I think of as good reasons), nor have I every used `Array.prototype.values`.  But together they make a really nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assume your `num` and `oper` are well-formatted, you can try this:

```
var num = [
  12, 13, 15, 22
];
var oper = [
  "+", "-", "*"
];

var exp = '';
while (num.length || oper.length) {
  if (num.length) {
    exp += num.shift();
  }
  if (oper.length) {
    exp += oper.shift();
  }
}

var result = eval(exp);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` and `eval` if you want to evaluate it as expression considering operator precedence

```js
var num = [ 12, 13, 15, 22 ];
var oper = [ "+", "-", "*" ];

let final = num.reduce((op,inp,index)=>{
  op += index === 0 ? inp : `${oper[index-1]} ${inp}`
  return op 
},'')

console.log(eval(final))
```

---

> **Original answer**

this doesn't count for operator precedence it just evaluates value from left two to right two oprand at a time,

```js
var num = [ 12, 13, 15, 22 ];
var oper = [ "+", "-", "*" ];

let final = num.reduce((op,inp,index)=>{
  if(index === 0) op += inp
  else {
    switch(oper[index-1]){
      case '+' : op += inp; break;
      case '-' : op -= inp; break;
      case '*' : op *= inp; break;
      default: op;
    }
  }
  return op
},0)

console.log(final)
```

Comment: Something not right ... 15x22 alone is more than final result

Comment: @charlietfl i am evaluating from left to right, two oprand at a time so it is calculating as `((12 + 13) - 15 ) * 22`

Comment: @charlietfl fixed

Comment: Sorry let me clear it up a bit. First thank you for your response. the operand order doesn't matter for my situation. It's in the order it appears. So a `+` can be before `*` if it appears first. The answer to the above should be `220`

Comment: @Si8 if you want to evaluate two values at a time without considering operator precedence than my original answer is enough, if you want to evaluate as expression considering operator precedence too you need to use the updated one

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for..of` loop and a chained ternary on each iteration no `eval()` required:

- Insure that the *numbers* array length is exactly one more element than *operators* array.
- `.splice()` the first two numbers of the *numbers* array -- resulting in the *terms* array.
- if *operator* is **`"+"`** -- add `terms[0]` to `terms[1]`
- else if *operator* is **`"-"`** -- subtract `terms[0]` from `terms[1]`
- else if *operator* is **`"*"`** -- multiply `terms[0]` by `terms[1]`
- else if *operator* is **`"/"`** -- divide `terms[0]` by `terms[1]`
- else -- **`NaN`**
- `unshift()` the result to index 0 of the *numbers* array.
- After the last iteration, return the first (and only) number of the *numbers* array after it passes as a real number otherwise an error message is returned instead.

```js
let numbers = [12, 13, 15, 22];
let operators = ["+", "-", "*"];

function calcArrays(numbers, operators) {
  operators.length = numbers.length - 1;
  for (let operator of operators) {
    let terms = numbers.splice(0, 2);
    let current = operator === '+' ? terms[0] + terms[1] :
      operator === '-' ? terms[0] - terms[1] :
      operator === '*' ? terms[0] * terms[1] :
      operator === '/' ? terms[0] / terms[1] : NaN;
    numbers.unshift(current);
  }
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(numbers[0])) && isFinite(numbers[0]) ? numbers[0] : 'Check parameters';
}

console.log(calcArrays(numbers, operators));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would define the binary functions that correspond to each possible value in `oper`, and then use `reduce` to get a left-to-right accumulation:

```js
const func = {
    "+": (a, b) => a + b,
    "-": (a, b) => a - b,
    "*": (a, b) => a * b,
    "/": (a, b) => a / b
};

const leftToRight = (nums, opers) => nums.reduce((a, b, i) => func[opers[i-1]](a, b));

console.log(leftToRight([12, 13, 15, 22], ["+", "-", "*"]));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add an object with the actual operations:

```
var opFunc = {
 '+': (a,b) => Number(a) + Number(b),
 '-': (a,b) => Number(a) - Number(b),
 '*': (a,b) => Number(a) * Number(b),
 '/': (a,b) => Number(a) / Number(b)
}
```

And then use reduce:

```js
var num = [
  12, 13, 15, 22
];
var oper = [
  "+", "-", "*"
];
var opFunc = {
 '+': (a,b) => Number(a) + Number(b),
 '-': (a,b) => Number(a) - Number(b),
 '*': (a,b) => Number(a) * Number(b),
 '/': (a,b) => Number(a) / Number(b)
}

var res = num.reduce((ac, x, i) =>
  opFunc[oper[i - 1]](ac,x)
)

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of useful approaches already presented.  I think one that's missing is to combine your data into a stack, and then process it as would a stack-based processor.

Here `makeStack` simply intersperses your values into a single array, `evalStack` takes a mapping of operator names to binary functions and the interspersed array, returning a `value`, and `process` simply combines those operations into a single function.

```js
const makeStack = (num, oper) => 
  [ num[0], ...num .slice (1) .flatMap ( (n, i) => [n, oper[i]] ) ]

const evalStack = (ops, [a, b = undefined, op = undefined, ...xs]) =>
  b == undefined 
    ? a
    : evalStack(ops, [ops [op] (a, b), ...xs])

const process = (ops, num, oper) => 
  evalStack (ops, makeStack (num, oper))

const ops = {
  '+': (a, b) => a + b,
  '-': (a, b) => a - b,
  '*': (a, b) => a * b,
  '/': (a, b) => a / b,
  // ... whatever other operators you want
}

const num = [12, 13, 15, 22]
const oper = ["+", "-", "*"]

console .log (
  process (ops, num, oper)
)
```

It would take a more sophisticated version of `evalStack`, but this could be extended to allow unary operators, or many more sophisticated stack manipulations functions.  Pretty soon you might be coding in [Forth](https://www.forth.com/forth/) !

Note that there is no error checking.  As always, that's an exercise left for the reader.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Never heard of Forth but it's great to know :). I wonder what other programming languages are out there that I haven't heard of yet. I will test out your code and let you know how it went. Thanks again @Scott

Answer (score 0):

Your "oper" array stores the "operators" as strings.  The line `retVal += num[t] oper[t] num[t+1]`, at the first iteration of your loop, is performing the following assignment:

```
retVal += 12 "+" 13
```

`12 "+" 13` is not valid syntax, it is simply two numbers and a string side-by-side. This does nothing.

Additionally, during the last iteration of your for loop, you will be referencing a non-existent index of the `num` array. `t` is `3`, and `num[3+1]`, that is, `num[4]`, does not exist. You will need to fix your for logic so that you stay within the bounds of your arrays.

There are a several ways to go about performing the operations specified in your `oper` array. For example, you could concatenate the array elements into a string, then evaluate the string using the `eval()` function. A simplistic implementation, assuming `num` and `oper` are guaranteed to be formatted correctly might look like this:

```
var num = [ 12, 13, 15, 22 ];
var oper = [ "+", "-", "*" ];
var expression = "";
for (var i = 0; i < oper.length; i++ ) {
    expression += String(num[i]) + oper[i];
}
expression += num[oper.length];
return eval(expression);
```

I recommend tailoring the loop logic to your application; what I implemented is just for the sake of demonstration. The important part is that the string, `expression`, is evaluated. If you inspect `epxression`, you will see that it is `"12+13-15*22"`. The return value is, correctly, `-305`.

Another technique may be to evaluate the elements of `oper` using a switch statement.

```
var num = [ 12, 13, 15, 22 ];
var oper = [ "+", "-", "*" ];
var result = num[0]
for (var i = 0; i < oper.length; i++ ) {
    switch(oper[i]) {
      case '+' : result += num[i+1]; break;
      case '-' : result -= num[i+1]; break;
      case '*' : result *= num[i+1]; break;
    }
}
return eval(result);
```

Unlike the `eval()` technique, this returns `220`. That is because the operations are performed exactly in the order of the `oper` array, rather than in the mathematical order of operations.

This order of operations should be a consideration in what method you decide to implement.

And to re-iterate, the for loops in my examples are for demonstration of this particular example, only, and could very well fail under other conditions. Build your logic around which values of `num` and `oper` you might expect in actual usage.

Comment: Thanks Ian for the answer